# Newbie can't figure this out for the life of me. swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a simple app in xcode to teach myself swift. I keep getting an error on the last line of the code below and I can't figure it out. when this compiles it says that this ColorArray isn't defined in this view.

```
class Colors: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Colorbox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var colorLabel: UILabel!
    var colorindex = 0
    var ColorArray = [
        UIColor.redColor(),
        UIColor.orangeColor(),
        UIColor.yellowColor(),
        UIColor.greenColor(),
        UIColor.blueColor(),
        UIColor.purpleColor(),
        UIColor.blackColor()
    ]
    var colornamesarray = [
        "Red",
        "Orange",
        "Yellow",
        "Green",
        "Blue",
        "Purple",
        "Black"
    ]

    @IBAction func ColorSwitchButton(sender: UIButton) {
        self.colorindex = self.colorindex+1
        print ("rotateColor: \(self.colorindex)")
        if (self.colorindex == self.colornamesarray.count){
            self.colorindex = 0}
    }
    let colorchoice = self.ColorArray[self.colorindex]
}
```

Comment: please also include the error that you are facing

Comment: It looks like you are missing a closing brace } at the last line. Your } is lined up with the func but is closing the if

Comment: do: lazy var colorchoice: UIColor = self.ColorArray[self.colorindex] instead. ...or var colorchoice: UIColor { return self.ColorArray[self.colorindex] }.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this line:

```
let colorchoice = self.ColorArray[self.colorindex]
```

appears *outside any function* (note that it is after the closing curly brace of your ColorSwitchButton function). Thus, it is at the top level of your class declaration, and declares a property `colorchoice`. But you cannot declare a property with reference to another property (`self.ColorArray` and `self.colorindex`).

Answer (score -1):

I definitely see where I was wrong. But I think a possible solution is to use a computed property for `colorchoice` like so:

```
let colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor()]

let colorIndex = 0

var colorchoice: UIColor {
   return colors[colorIndex]
}
```

**incorrect first statement: (for reference)**

It may be that `colorindex` should never be = to `colornamesarray.count` because arrays in swift are zero indexed. You may want to try `if colorindex == (colornamesarray.count - 1)` instead.

Comment: Since they increment `colorindex` at the start of the function, it could be equal to `colornamesarray.count` and that is why they use the `if` statement to reset the index to 0